# Google Sheet importxml login access

Tags: xml, xpath, google-sheets, ebay-api

I've used importxml to get public info from a website. But sometimes info changed when we access though different country. For example http://www.ebay.com/itm/221998403138?_trksid=p2057872.m2749.l2649&var=520870142881

this item is not available in USA but when we'll access from different country where seller shipped or changed the country of shipping, we can find the shipping cost. If I use importxml from Google Sheet, that means the access country will be USA. How far I understand i can't change the IP of Google Sheet. So I would like to know if is there any way to sent login detail though URL. That means I want to specific Google Sheet to access URL though my login details(username and password).

So that shipping cost will appear under xpath.

**//*[@id="fshippingCost"]/span[1]  -- Non-US country where seller ship**

**//*[@id="shSummary"]/span[1]  - USA, shipping is not available**

Please see the image for clarification.

http://prntscr.com/ad6fqi

Answer (score 2):

IMPORTXML is a Google Sheets built-in function that use Google servers to be ran anonymously. The same applies to IMPORTDATA, IMPORTFEED, IMPORTHTML.

If you need to sign in in order to get access to restricted access information you should use another thing like the URL Fetch Service from Google Apps Script. It could be used to create a custom function like [IMPORTJSON](https://github.com/bradjasper/ImportJSON), or other types of scripts.

Related

- [How to know if Google Sheets IMPORTDATA, IMPORTFEED, IMPORTHTML or IMPORTXML functions are able to get data from a resource hosted on a website?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/115664/88163)

References

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions